# Spring Servlet Mapping from *.html to SO type mapping

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc, mapping

I have a spring app with one servlet that has url-mapping of *.html.  Everything is working great with my annotated controllers.

My question is how can I setup my servlet and annotated mappings to mimic the urls like StackOverflow?

I would like to go to a no extension url and if possible add a description after the final /.

Example:

I currently have:

```
/appName/parm1/parm2/pageName.html
```

I would like to have

```
/appName/parm1/parm2/pageName/description
```

Is this possible and what do I need to do to my annotated controllers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to map the dispatcher servlet to /* or something like that, and then use @PathVariables to get the needed information from the URI.  Have a look at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html and search for @PathVariable.  Here's an example from that page

```
@RequestMapping(value="/owners/{ownerId}/pets/{petId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String findPet(@PathVariable String ownerId, @PathVariable String petId, Model model) {
  Owner owner = ownerService.findOwner(ownerId);  
  Pet pet = owner.getPet(petId);  
  model.addAttribute("pet", pet);  
  return "displayPet"; 
}
```

which reads the ownerId and the petId from the request uri.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have all that working currently.  I tried to do /* and it caused everything to break.  I was also interested in how can you display the description at the end of the url without having spring trying to render it as the view name.  Thanks

Comment: On the /* issue, I'm not at a place where I can look at my spring project, so I'll have to look at that later.  You should be able to do a RequestMapping like @RequestMapping9value="/questions/{questionId}/{questionDescription}and then you can discard the questionDescription if you want and just use the questionId.